# How to protect against changing mail server AS IS?

Tags: email, dns, postfix

In DNS we can setup an IP for `mx.example.com` in A-record, after we can setup `@` for domain controlled by `mx.example.com` in MX-record.

Since this moment everyone know, what when you want to sent mail to `admin@example.com` you should connect `mx.example.com` what on IP adress from A record.

Next situation: someone installed new server on same IP (i.e. new VPS/DS on same IP in datacenter) with mailserver what accept connections on port 25.

In such case when someone will send mail to `admin@example.com` his mailserver will connect 'mx.example.com', but its NOT the same server anymore. Message will be sent, to someone.

Is it possible to add kind of digest in DNS records to protect against siatuation when someone changed your server?

DKIM - work for outgoing mails. But how sender (=server) can check what recipient is on valid server?

Comment: DNS isn't designed to address this kind of issue. half the point of DNS is to abstract away the physical identity of a box so that it can be more dynamically mapped to names.

Comment: Finally, yes, designed. TLSA records. DNSSEC -> TLSA -> server connection and if fingerprint different with data from TLSA, client should to close connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally:

TLSA - for certificates

SSHFP - for ssh connections